# Forward traffic between 2 network interfaces in one Laptop

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have an ethernet module (a sensor but communicating via ethernet: TCP/IP) connecting to my laptop (x1 carbon). An android device (Pixel XL) in USB tethering mode connecting to my Laptop.

[image]

IP of ethernet module: 192.168.0.12 (set by me) -> interface in Laptop: 192.168.0.111 (static) (set by me)

IP of a Pixel: 192.168.42.129 (default of the phone) -> interface in Laptop: 192.168.0.29 (static) (set by me)

Now I want to forward packet from Pixel to the ethernet module and vice versa (ping at first). How can I do it? Please instruct in detail because I do not have the network background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am using both ubuntu and windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solve instead of using Android device, I replaced it by another embedded PC. We have to run routing in 3 devices.

For Windows, and Linux (Ubuntu) using `route add`